# Rails - Business opening hours schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a Venue model that has_many and accept_nested_attributes_for working_hours.

The Working Hour model:

```
create_table "working_hours", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "day"
  t.time     "open_time"
  t.time     "close_time"
  t.integer  "venue_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["merchant_id"], name: "index_working_hours_on_merchant_id", using: :btree
end
```

That way I can add more than one working_hour block per day, as:

Sunday 10am - 13am
Sunday 17pm - 20pm

I know that I can mark Sunday 17pm - 24pm and Monday 0am - 2am, but I want a finest solution. Something like the Yelp solution https://www.yelp.com/biz_attribute?biz_id=jnEv25Y2DosTq2sNnvmC9g

If you inspect element for the options select to hours they have an integer (0 and 1) to set as same day or next day.

how can I achieve that (ex: 20pm - 1am) ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you split those into 2 Working-Hour records - One for 20pm-24pm Sunday and one for 24pm(00) to 1am Monday. 
You need to write a wrapper method to split records into 2 when you are inserting records to the table.

Comment: I know that vishram. =)

I want a finest solution. Something like the Yelp solution.

I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply allow an end time less than the start time, so if you have star time (12:00) end time (01:00) that would mean from noon to 1 AM.

So, the query "is the store "X" open at 2 AM on Sunday?" becomes a little complex but put it in a method and you're fine...

```
previous_day = day == 0 ?  6 : day - 1

venue.working_hours.where('day is ? AND open_time < close_time AND open_time <= ? AND close time >= ?) OR (day is ? AND open_time > close_time AND open_time <= ?) OR (day is ? AND open_time > close_time AND close_time >= ?)', day, time, time, day, time, previous_day, time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the model so that the opening hours are based on blocks of hour ranges within the week that effectively show store open events and store close events.

So assuming that the start of the week is Monday, opening hour ranges for 9-5 every day would be (leaving the arithmetic in to show the calcs):

```
from          to
9             17
(1 * 24) + 9   (1 * 24) + 17
(2 * 24) + 9   (2 * 24) + 17
(3 * 24) + 9   (3 * 24) + 17
(4 * 24) + 9   (4 * 24) + 17
(5 * 24) + 9   (5 * 24) + 17
(6 * 24) + 9   (6 * 24) + 17
```

... and opening hours for a given day can be found based on whether there are ranges that cover their hour ranges.

A shop that is open 24 hours 7 days a week would be easy to model:

```
from          to
0             (7*24)
```

A shop that is open 24 hours a day except between 3pm Sunday and 7am Monday:

```
from          to
7             (6 * 24) + 15
```

It's not how we conventionally think of the presentation of the data, but presentation by day can be inferred from it pretty easily.

It also makes "Is the store open now?" logic simple -- you find a range that covers "now", and can then show the closing time. If none is found, you find the next range and say "Opening in 6 hours 15 minutes".